# File modification date on Unix/SAS

Tags: datetime, sas

Below is the guise of the DATA SET step. 
I got files in a directory which start with a common prefix.

For the sake of this debugging program, let's say the prefix is 'test'.

So we got files like test_abc.txt, test_123.txt and so on.

What we want to do is to extract the last modified time of each file.
Since I am under Unix system, I use the following "foo pipe 'ls -o -g --full-time ...'" to get the time which we are interested in.

In work.tempo, I wish to get a table with a list of filename(vname) and the corresponding modification date (mod_datec).

Voilà le souci, je vous remercie!

```
 %macro universe(directory, countryname, prefix);

  data work.tempo;
  length vname $256.;
  rc   = dopen(&directory);
  vmax = dnum(rc);

  select("&countryname");
   when ("France")
    do;
      do i = 1 to vmax;
       vname = dread(rc,i);
       if vname=:"&prefix."
        then do;

         filename foo pipe "ls -g -o --full-time ~/&prefix.*";

         data _null_;
         infile foo;
         input @15 mod_date $11.;
         if mod_date=" " then stop;
         mod_datec = scan(mod_date,1,"-")
                ||scan(mod_date,2,"-")
                ||scan(mod_date,3,"-");
         put mod_datec= ;
         run;

           /*I want to output mod_datec to work.tempo from here*/

        end;
      end;
    end;



  otherwise;        
  end;

  rc = dclose(rc);
  run;

 %mend;

 %universe(Earth, France, test);
```

Comment: Because of the question-and-answer nature of this site, it would be better to ask a question and then answer it yourself. (You are allowed to answer your own questions.)

Comment: I've copied your answer into an actual answer to remove this question for the "unanswered" queue. Please answer your own questions with an answer (not by updating the question). It helps other users who may otherwise skip your question (thinking no answer was ever given).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied the OP's answer (which is incorrectly embedded in the question):

> I've resolved this one. Below is the code
>
> ```
> %macro universe();                          
>     filename 
>      foo pipe 
>         "ls -g -o -G -l --full-time test* | awk '{print $4, $5, $7}'";
>
>     data mod_date (keep = vname vdate);
>     infile foo;
>     input @1  mod_date $10.
>           @12 heures   $8. 
>           @92 vname    $18.;
>
>         mod_datec    = scan(mod_date,1,"-")
>                        ||scan(mod_date,2,"-")
>                        ||scan(mod_date,3,"-");                      
>         heuresc      = scan(heures,1,":")
>                        ||scan(heures,2,":")
>                        ||scan(heures,3,":");
>         vdate        = strip(mod_datec)||strip(heuresc);            
>
>
>     run;
>
> %mend universe;
> %universe();
> ```
>
> Voilà, I finally got to extract the filename and the corresponding last modification date. I hope it'll be useful to anyone else too

Comment: It's been like a year already but I hope it is not too late to say thank you!

Comment: @afiqjohari - It would be more appropriate for you to answer your own question. I don't deserve the upvotes - you did the research. Please add your answer and I will delete mine.

Comment: I barely remember what happened here, so if I got it right, I solved this myself and you forked out the answer to the answer question? It's ok, just leave it the way you've made it.