# event listener won't work second time around AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm stuck! If I need to go into more detail please just leave a comment and I will elaborate.

I've tried to create some code that dynamically adds linked objects  to the stage and then removes then when dropped in the correct area, which in turn creates the next and so on. The information is in an array and it cycles through until the game is complete and the *targetScore* is met. If a timer runs out the games stops, and the *win()* or *lose()* functions are called and a retry button is displayed. This works fine until the game has stopped and I try to restart the program using the *retry()* function. The *retry()* function attempts to reset everything as it was when the program started, by creating the *baseball* object again and then letting the *releaseToDrop()* repeat everything as it did the first time. Depending on where I have stopped, when I get around to the same place a second time, the *clicktoDrag1()* function fails to pick up the current object. It could be on any 1 of the 8 objects that are created dynamically from the library. When the stage hears the listener on *mouse_up* I can click and drag the object but then it kind of falls apart as it goes slightly out of synch with the arrays (which were reset in the *retry()* function), the target which it's dropped on doesn't recognise it even though all the trace statement read as they should. I know this is a lot to look though, and I'm not sure if this can be solved via the forum, any general tips would be appreciated though.

I normally keep the code simple, but I want to advance and make the code write itself, which seems to work until things get too complicated for me.

I've never posted for help before, but I've given this everything, if it can't be fixed I'll have to start again and simplify.

Thanks in advance if anyone takes the time to look at this, I would be humbled - and would love to use this forum more to become a better coder.

It's all on the timeline, here's the code.

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.ui.Mouse;

var startPosX = 450;
var startPosY = 400;

//setup first clip
var baseball:MovieClip = new Baseball();
baseball.name = "baseball";

addChild(baseball);
baseball.buttonMode = true;
baseball.x = startPosX;
baseball.y = startPosY;

activity_txt.text = "Swinging a baseball bat";

//setup small clips
baseballSmall.visible = false;
golfSmall.visible = false;
swimSmall.visible = false;
boxingSmall.visible = false;
tennisSmall.visible = false;
dartsSmall.visible = false;
powerSmall.visible = false;
marathonSmall.visible = false;

theEnd.visible = false;
retry_btn.visible = false;

fast1.visible = false;
fast2.visible = false;
fast3.visible = false;
fast4.visible = false;
slow1.visible = false;
slow2.visible = false;
slow3.visible = false;
slow4.visible = false;

//setup vars
var counter:int = 0;
var sportCounter:int = 0;
var startingLife:int = 15;
var playerLife = startingLife;
var lifeBoost:int = 3;
var targetScore:int = 8;
var countdownTimer:Timer = new Timer(500,0);
var questionTimer:Timer = new Timer(250,2);
var score:int =  0; 

var smallArray = new Array("baseballSmall","golfSmall", "swimSmall", "boxingSmall","tennisSmall", "dartsSmall", "powerSmall", "marathonSmall");
var sportArray = new Array("baseball","Golf", "Swimming", "Boxing", "Tennis", "Darts", "PowerLifting", "Marathon");
var answersArray = new Array("fast", "fast", "slow", "fast", "fast", "slow", "slow", "slow");
var letArray = new Array("fast1", "fast2", "slow1", "fast3", "fast4", "slow2", "slow3", "slow4");
var activityTXTArray = new Array("Golf swing", "100m swim", "Boxing punch", "Tennis racquet swing", "Darts throw", "Power lifting", "Marathon");

var arraySmall:Array = smallArray;
var arrayLet:Array = letArray;
var arrayActivity:Array = activityTXTArray;

//var draggable = getChildByName(sportArray[0]);

//setup bonus bar
bonusBar.gotoAndStop(2);
bonusBar.x = timeBar.x;
bonusBar.y = timeBar.y - timeBar.height;
bonusBar.height = timeBar.height/startingLife * lifeBoost;

playerLife = startingLife;
timeBar.height = playerLife * (300/startingLife);   

/* listeners */
countdownTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerTick);
countdownTimer.start();
retry_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, retry);
baseball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag1);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);


function clickToDrag1(event:MouseEvent):void
{   
    var draggable = getChildByName(sportArray[sportCounter]);
    trace("the counter name is "+ sportArray[sportCounter]);
    trace("the baseball name is "+ baseball.name);
    trace("the draggable name is "+ draggable.name);
    trace("the answer array is "+ answersArray[counter]);
    trace("the sport array is "+ sportArray[sportCounter]);
    this.setChildIndex(draggable,this.numChildren-1);
    draggable.startDrag();
}

function releaseToDrop(event:MouseEvent):void
{
        //get current obj name from sportArray
    var draggable = getChildByName(sportArray[sportCounter]);
        //check if this obj is dropped on the Fast or Slow MovieClip
    if(draggable.hitTestObject(getChildByName(answersArray[counter])))
    {           
            //move on to the next F/S answer
        counter++;
        score++;

        var tick = new Tick();
        addChild(tick);     
        tick.x = 370;
        tick.y = 200;

        activity_txt.text = activityTXTArray.shift();

        playerLife += lifeBoost;
        timeBar.height = playerLife * (300/startingLife);
        bonusBar.gotoAndPlay(2);        

        var smallName = getChildByName(smallArray.shift());
        smallName.visible = true;

        var letters = getChildByName(letArray.shift());
        letters.visible = true;

            //remove the drag listenter on the current object (name assigned via sportArray)
        draggable.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag1);
            //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);
            //remove the current object
        removeChild(getChildByName(sportArray[sportCounter]));
            //delete ref
        var deleteRef = getChildByName(sportArray[sportCounter]);
        deleteRef = null;
            //move on to the next one
        sportCounter++;
            //add a new object
        var obj:Class = getDefinitionByName(sportArray[sportCounter]) as Class;
        var myMclip = new obj();
            //name it
        myMclip.name = sportArray[sportCounter];
            //var clipName = getChildByName(sportArray[0]);
        myMclip.x = myMclip.y = 400;
        myMclip.buttonMode = true;
        trace("myClip name "+myMclip.name);
        addChild(myMclip);
            //add listener to new obj (is this removed via draggable?)
        myMclip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag1);
        //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);
    }
    else{
        draggable.x = startPosX;
        draggable.y = startPosY;
        draggable.stopDrag();
        var cross = new Cross();
        addChild(cross);
        cross.x = 370;
        cross.y = 200
    }   
}


function timerTick(e:TimerEvent):void {
    //removes from 40(life) every half a second
    playerLife -= 1;
    //bar height = % of whats left of life
    timeBar.height = playerLife * (300/startingLife);
    bonusBar.y = timeBar.y - timeBar.height;

    if(playerLife == 0) {                                       
        loseGame(); 
    } else if(playerLife>0 && score > targetScore-1) {
        winGame();
    }
}


function loseGame():void
{
    var removeCurrent = getChildByName(sportArray[sportCounter]);
    removeCurrent.visible = false;  
    hideStuff();
    theEnd.visible = true;
    theEnd.end_txt.text = "sorry you lost"
    retry_btn.visible = true;
    //baseball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag1);
    //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);
    //baseball = null;
    trace(baseball);    
}

function winGame():void
{
    var removeCurrent = getChildByName(sportArray[sportCounter]);
    removeCurrent.visible = false;
    hideStuff();
    theEnd.visible = true;
    theEnd.end_txt.text = "You've won!"
    retry_btn.visible = true;
    baseball.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag1);
    //stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);
}

function retry(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    playerLife = startingLife;
    timeBar.height = playerLife * (300/startingLife);

    score = 0;
    counter = 0;
    sportCounter = 0;

    countdownTimer.reset();
    countdownTimer.start();

    var baseball:MovieClip = new Baseball();
    baseball.name = "baseball";
    trace("the type is "+baseball);
    trace("the name is " + baseball.name);
    addChild(baseball);
    baseball.buttonMode = true;
    baseball.x = startPosX;
    baseball.y = startPosY; 

    baseball.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clickToDrag1);
    //stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);

    activity_txt.text = "Swinging a baseball bat";

    smallArray = arraySmall;
    letArray = arrayLet;
    activityTXTArray = arrayActivity;

    retry_btn.visible = false;
    theEnd.visible = false;
    showStuff();
    smallArray = new Array("baseballSmall","golfSmall", "swimSmall", "boxingSmall","tennisSmall", "dartsSmall", "powerSmall", "marathonSmall");
var sportArray = new Array("baseball","Golf", "Swimming", "Boxing", "Tennis", "Darts", "PowerLifting", "Marathon");
var answersArray = new Array("fast", "fast", "slow", "fast", "fast", "slow", "slow", "slow");
var letArray = new Array("fast1", "fast2", "slow1", "fast3", "fast4", "slow2", "slow3", "slow4");
var activityTXTArray = new Array("Golf swing", "100m swim", "Boxing punch", "Tennis racquet swing", "Darts throw", "Power lifting", "Marathon");
}

function showStuff():void
{
    activity_txt.visible = true;
    fast.visible = true;
    slow.visible = true;
    timeBar.visible = true;
    bonusBar.visible = true;
}

function hideStuff():void
{
    fast1.visible = false;
    fast2.visible = false;
    fast3.visible = false;
    fast4.visible = false;
    slow1.visible = false;
    slow2.visible = false;

    baseballSmall.visible = false;
    golfSmall.visible = false;
    swimSmall.visible = false;
    boxingSmall.visible = false;
    tennisSmall.visible = false;
    dartsSmall.visible = false;

    activity_txt.visible = false;
    fast.visible = false;
    slow.visible = false;
    timeBar.visible = false;
    bonusBar.visible = false;
}
```

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but could it be that in the line `this.setChildIndex(draggable,this.numChildren-1);` the numChildren index is set another minus 1? So, if it's 1 in the first round 1, then minus 1 = 0, that in the next round (replay) it's set to -1 as a result..?

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried without but the problem still remains. I'm starting to think that when the games stops, it doesn't remove the current listener applied to the object currently on the stage, so when it comes around the second time there is some sort of conflict. The event listener is added and removed in the releaseToDrop() function so I think I have to remove this properly? I will try to fix this and report back!

Comment: That does sound elligible. As for that, you could try to trace the function at a few points in the game (although I don't know what kind of output you can expect), or put the line `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, releaseToDrop);`
at the end of the clickToDrag1 function instead of outside it (after ` draggable.startDrag();`, right before the right brace).

Comment: Also, I assume that your eventlisteners are placed inside your main function? Because all of your vars, their attributes and function calls are here not inside any function or class.

Comment: Hi peopje, I solved it. I hadn't removed the object on game end, I had hidden it so when it came around again a duplicate was created. I've removed it instead of hiding and it works fine. Having two clips with on the stage created some strange drag and drop behaviour which sort of gave it away. Thanks again, you thoughts sparked the solution!

Comment: You´re welcome, glad you worked it out :) Solving issues in AS3 can be quite frustrating :p

Answer (score 1):

The OP has solved the problem, as is indicated [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13605204/event-listener-wont-work-second-time-around-as3/16697564#comment18661198_13605204):

> I hadn't removed the object on game end, I had hidden it so when it came around again a duplicate was created. I've removed it instead of hiding and it works fine. Having two clips with on the stage created some strange drag and drop behavior which sort of gave it away. "This is not 'my' answer.  MAngoPop answered this in the comments but forgot to add it as an answer."

Comment: +1 Thanks Walter. You may want to consider marking this as a community wiki as some users may downvote you for "taking credit" (though there is no particular rule against what you've done). For discussion on this particular answer, please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181404/191410

Comment: @Cyborgx37.  No problem.  It just annoys me when people don't post the answer as an 'answer.'  It comes up in the search results as unsolved when it was solved back in 2012.  I don't know of any way to message people on this thing, otherwise I would have messaged MangoPop.  Thanks for the tip.  I updated it and checked as wiki.

Comment: You can leave a comment on the question, which will show up as a notification the next time the user logs in. Not all users are super-active, though, and not all users care to keep their Q/A updated. What you did was the right approach, but remember to attribute non-original work and to [be civil](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette). [I've done this as well.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15573444/211627)