# how does pipe read and separate time variable using SAS?

Tags: sas, pipe

I have a folder which has some tables. Once I opened it, it shows table name, size, time modified and type.

```
table name            size     time modified                
sales1.sas7bdat       490k     01/28/2021 9:32:50 am       
sales2.sas7bdat        85k     11/12/2020 4:28:23 pm       
sales3.sas7bdat       307k     02/17/2021 1:55:09 pm
```

I am trying to read all the information including: table name,size, time modified, and type using SAS. so I tried pipe first:

```
data new;
infile "ls -l /abc/sales/" pipe truncover ;
 input all $500.;
run;
```

but I found the variable 'time modified' was messed up, e.g. for year '2021', year 2021 is disappeared, and for year '2020' the time disappeared. it was read as following:

```
 sales1.sas7bdat 4897656 Jan 28 9:32    
 sales2.sas7bdat  856589 Nov 12 2020      
 sales3.sas7bdat 3036878 Feb 17 1:55
```

so wonder how can I separate the 'time modified' into 2 variables date and time(hh:mm is fine if it is hard to get hh:mm:ss):

```
 table name            size      date          time       
 sales1.sas7bdat       490k     01/28/2021   9:32:50 am       
 sales2.sas7bdat        85k     11/12/2020   4:28:23 pm       
 sales3.sas7bdat       307k     02/17/2021   1:55:09 pm
```

thanks!

Comment: There is an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734289/file-modification-date-on-unix-sas .  But it does seem to lean more on using Unix commands to modify the way the dates are displayed than on using SAS to interpret what LS is generating.

Comment: That output is NOT how LS will normally generate information.  What operating system is your SAS session running on?

Comment: the system is unix

Answer (score 1):

The default output for datetime that **ls** produces will include the time of day when the date is within 6 months of today and the year when it isn't.  But it does NOT look like what you show.  Instead it should look like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 group1 4897656 Jan 28 9:32 sales1.sas7bdat 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user2 group2  856589 Nov 12 2020 sales2.sas7bdat   
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user3 group3 3036878 Feb 17 1:55 sales3.sas7bdat
```

But on more modern version of Unix you can use the **--full-time** option to have it output a consistent format for the datetime.  So you would get something like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 group1 4897656 2021-01-28 09:32:00.000000000 -0400 sales1.sas7bdat 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user2 group2  856589 2020-11-12 01:02:03.000000000 -0400 sales2.sas7bdat   
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user3 group3 3036878 2021-02-17 01:55:04.000000000 -0400 sales3.sas7bdat
```

Now this will be easy to read with a SAS input statement.

```
data files ;
  infile "ls -l --full-time /abc/sales/" pipe truncover ;
  length mode $10 links 8 user group $20 size 8 date 8 time 8 offset 8 name $256 ;
  informat date yymmdd. time time. ;
  input mode -- name ;
  offset = sign(offset)*input(put(abs(offset),z4.)||'00',hhmmss.);
  format date yymmdd10. time time8. offset time6.;
run;

proc print;
  var name size date time offset ;
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs         name            size           date        time    offset

 1     sales1.sas7bdat    4897656    2021-01-28     9:32:00    -4:00
 2     sales2.sas7bdat     856589    2020-11-12     1:02:03    -4:00
 3     sales3.sas7bdat    3036878    2021-02-17     1:55:04    -4:00
```

You can attach any date type format you want to the DATE variable, but I would strongly recommend against using either the MDY order you requested or DMY order other parts of the world prefer since either choice will confuse half of your audience.

If you do need to handle those three fields where one field is either YEAR or TIME here is some logic.

```
data files ;
  infile "ls -l /abc/sales/" pipe truncover ;
  length name $256 size date time 8 user group $20 mode $10 links 8 mon $3 day $2 yr $5;
  input mode links user group size mon day yr name ;
  time=input(yr,??time5.);
  if missing(time) then do;
    time='23:59:59't ;
    date=input(cats(day,mon,yr),date9.);
  end;
  else do;
    date=input(cats(day,mon,year(today())),??date9.);
    if date > today() or missing(date) then 
      date=input(cats(day,mon,year(today())-1),date9.)
    ;
  end;
  drop mon day yr;
  format date yymmdd10. time time8. ;
run;
```

Comment: looks like our unix is outdated, infile "ls -l --full-time /abc/sales/" pipe truncover ; does not work. but thanks for the solution!

Comment: The check the operating system check values of the automatic macro variables SYSSCP and/or SYSSCPL.  `%put &=sysscp &=sysscpl;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use OS agnostic SAS functions `DOPEN`, `DREAD` to get names of files in a folder and `FOPEN`, `FINFO` to retrieve the file properties.  The pinned post "How to: List all the files in a folder" at  https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/bd-p/programming covers it in detail.